# Create interface with field that must have different enum types in derived classes

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, enums, interface

I have 3 classes that have almost same fields:

```
public DateTime Date { get; set; }

public long? Value { get; set; }

public (Enum1 or Enum2 or Enum3) Type { get; set; }
```

So for them I want to create some interface. But I don't know how to add `Type` field to it.

Maybe it is impossible as Enums are value types and can be derived only from System.Enum, but maybe there are some solution.

Comment: Won't `IMyInterface<T> { T Type {get;set;} }` work? You could use it like `Class1 : IMyInterface<Enum1>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use generics for that:

```
public enum TypeA { }
public enum TypeB { }
public enum TypeC { }

public interface I<T> where T : struct
{
    DateTime Date { get; set; }
    long? Value { get; set; }
    T Type { get; set; }
}

public class A : I<TypeA>
{
    DateTime Date { get; set; }
    long? Value { get; set; }
    public TypeA Type { get; set; }
}

public class B : I<TypeB>
{
    DateTime Date { get; set; }
    long? Value { get; set; }
    public TypeB Type { get; set; }
}

public class C : I<TypeC>
{
    DateTime Date { get; set; }
    long? Value { get; set; }
    public TypeC Type { get; set; }
}
```

---

> **Edit from the comments:** If you are're already using C# 7.3, you can use `where T : struct, Enum` as constraint, where the `Enum` constrains it to enums, but since it still allow the `Enum` class (which is not an enum), you could keep the `struct` constraint as well.

Comment: Better to add a constraint on the type `where T : struct`

Comment: @DavidG good but better with C# 8 I think they will add enum constraint for generic. So we'll just use `where T : Enum`. I saw it in the Build 2018 Future of C#.

Comment: @CodeNotFound it's available in c# 7.3 but I will maintain the struct constraint too `where T : struct, Enum`.

Comment: @CodeNotFound - `where T : Enum` unfortunately allows `System.Enum` which isn't an enum type which is why the `struct` constraint is still required too.

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria Thanks. you're right :) More information about that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7-3#enhanced-generic-constraints) and some explanations [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yep the previous comment to yours already said that.

Comment: It said to still use it, it didn't elaborate on *why*, which I thought could be a useful extra detail.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I added these details to the answer, as I find them very helpful. I would appreciate any feedback or edits if I wasn't clear enough (or explained it wrongly).